# Django: Raw sql query to get CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is not updating on subsequent calls

Tags: django, postgresql

I have the following snippet of code used to get the current timestamp from the db server:

```
class DbUtils:
    @staticmethod
    def get_current_timestamp():
        from django.db import connection
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
        rows = cursor.fetchone()
        return rows[0]
```

To test this code I wrote the following test:

```
def test_get_current_timestamp(self):
    ts_0 = DbUtils.get_current_timestamp()
    time.sleep(1)
    ts_1 = DbUtils.get_current_timestamp()
    delta_seconds = (ts_1 - ts_0).seconds
    assert 1 <= delta_seconds <= 3
```

This test was not passing so I dug into it a little bit. The reason was that each call to `DbUtils.get_current_timestamp()` was returning the same value each time.

```
In [31]: DbUtils.get_current_timestamp()
Out[31]: datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 1, 17, 17, 48, 950799, tzinfo=<UTC>)

# Wait a couple seconds

In [32]: DbUtils.get_current_timestamp()
Out[32]: datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 1, 17, 17, 48, 950799, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

I monitored the postgresql log - each query was hitting the db.

The only way I was able to make this work was to import django.db.transaction and execute `transaction.commit_unless_managed()` prior to executing the SELECT. Committing a transaction prior to the SELECT doesn't seem right since I don't know in what context get_current_timestamp will be called. Any ideas on how to fix this or work around it? The timestamp needs to come from the db server to ensure that all relative time calculations are done correctly.

I am running:

```
Django==1.4.2
psycopg2==2.4.5 (with hstore extension via django-hstore==1.1.1)
PostgreSQL 9.1
```

Comment: Check out the manual. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns the time at the start of the transaction! http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT you need to use something different if you want the "real" current time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After talking it over with a coworker we realized this actually might be desirable behavior since we would only every get one timestamp per web request. In any case, I was usually storing the return value of `get_current_timestamp` and using that for any operations during that request.

To make my test pass I needed to do the following:

```
def test_get_current_timestamp(self):
    from django.db import transaction
    ts_0 = DbUtils.get_current_timestamp()
    transaction.commit_unless_managed()
    time.sleep(1)
    ts_1 = DbUtils.get_current_timestamp()
    transaction.commit_unless_managed()
    delta_seconds = (ts_1 - ts_0).seconds
    assert 1 <= delta_seconds <= 3
```

As @a_horse_with_no_name notes: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is the time at the beginning of the transaction.